# jQuery Get Specific Content From External Page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

So I have something like

```
<ul>
<li> <a href="123.html">123</a></li>
<li> <a href="abc.html">abc</a></li>
</ul>
```

This sites in my INDEX.HTML file. Except there are loads more lists and list items. Each HTML page that is linked to has a section like this:

```
<ul>
<li><strong>Time: </strong>12:00</li>
</ul>
```

What I want is when the user sees the INDEX.HTML page, the time gets added to the end (from the relative link) so it reads like

- 123 - 12:00
- ABC - 13:00

Can someone please help? I realise I might need contents() and fine() but have got nowhere quick. So basically for each link, we go to the URL in question, grab the time and add it the original line on INDEX.HTML

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some JavaScript code so we can see what you're even talking about!

Comment: I don't see where you are attempting to get anything from the URL. are you trying to get parameters from the URL?

Comment: is there a reason you cant do this server side?

Comment: UPDATED - it has to be done in jQuery

Comment: "I do not think that means what you think that means."  If you are trying to get values from the URL as your title implies, than that would be core javascript.

Comment: "jQuery Get Specific Content From External Page"

Comment: I love jQuery as much as anybody but i still think solving your problem on the server side would save you a ton of time and from the looks of your website a few hundred ajax calls per pageload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea could be as follows:

1. Loop through the `li`s.
2. Get the `href` attribute of the `a` child.
3. Send an ajax request to that page.
4. Parse the response and find the appropriate text using jQuery.
5. Append that text to the `li`.

On jsFiddle it's not very easy to generate separate pages, so you'll have to alter it a bit for your case. Also, you may want to make the selector stricter (`ul strong` is the best I can make up with your example).

http://jsfiddle.net/3JQDz/

```
$("li").each(function() {
    var $li = $(this);
    var href = $li.find("a").attr("href");  // use this in your real case

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/echo/html/",  // this is just the way to use ajax on jsFiddle
        data: {
            html: "<ul><li><strong>Time: </strong>12:00</li></ul>"
        },
        success: function(html) {
            // full document -> only the li -> its child nodes -> the last one (the text node) -> its text
            var time = $(html).find("li").contents().last().text();
            $li.append(" - " + time);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What does the `html: "<ul><li><strong>Time: </strong>12:00</li></ul>"` do/mean? I managed to get the LI in question to have an ID of "TimeID"

Comment: @Janusz Jasinski: On jsFiddle that's the only way to get an ajax response back. It's representing your page as a dummy item. You can omit `data: {...}` in your real code.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem, I believe you want to load the contents of each inner page to display the information in the main menu. If this is the case, it is a bad idea for performance.

If you want even so, you will first need to load the HTML content using the [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function. Then work with the result, searching for the desired element.

**UPDATE**

I updated the [sample here](http://jsbin.com/acagif/2/). It has only one link, but now showing it with your code structure.

Based on it, I believe your `index.html` code will be something like this:

```
$("li a").each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("href");
    $.get(src, function(data) {
      var element = $("<div>").html(data);
      var time = element.find("li").contents().last().text();
      $("li").append(" - " + time);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks - this is the web page I am working with - http://readingfestival.com/line-up/ - trying but getting nowhere fast. Maybe because it's been a long day!

Comment: I created another `js.bin` with your inner page structure, then I updated the main page with the new code. I hope it helps you.